# How to reduce seams when texture painting

Tags: uv, texture-painting

It is very annoying when you are trying to texture paint an object and you get this:

[image: TexturePaintingProbs]

It appears that it is like a seam resulting from bad UV unwraping.  What can I do to help prevent this?  I am not good at UV unwrapping.

Comment: Please show your UV Map ... so people can inspect it and give you better instruction.  Have you tried any techniques to hide part of your mesh while painting?

Comment: How can you hide your mesh while painting?  When I switch back to texture paint mode it displays all mesh whether hidden or not.

Comment: All I did for a UV map was Smart UV unwrapping.  I think it puts in automatic seams.  I would prefer, in order to stay anonymous, to not show my model, but perhaps I could make an example?

Comment: In your tool Options panel, increase your bleed from default 2 pixels to maybe 4 or 6 pixels. Also, this problem can sometimes be from the problems in viewport from the actual projection  from too far away with the brush - and then moving the view and zooming in to paint sometimes helps. Are you on 2.8 or 2.79 right now?

Comment: Hey, I upped the bleed as you said, and it worked great!  If I find any more problems I'll comment, but it looks like that'll work.  Thanks!  I suggest you post the last comment as an answer.  And, in answer to your question, I am still on 2.79

Comment: Just experimented a little more with it, and the bleed problem doesn't completely fix the problem, but it helps.  Instead of leaving a seam unpainted, it causes paint to "travel" up the seam further than you intended it to.  If you've got any ideas, that's great.  I'm not terribly worried about it, however.  I can probably get a good result if I fiddle with it long enough.  Thankyou for your help!